# Microsoft Graph API security

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

For one of our shared customers we are working on improving the security of their Azure suite.
This customer has client information stored on a OneDrive for Business drive. They download data files from this drive using an application that integrates with the Graph REST API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

We noticed that this API call generates a temporary public URI with which the content can be downloaded. This public URI is, however, completely unsecured and can be opened by anyone that manages to intercept this URI.

Is there a way to either:

- Lock this URI to a specific IP address
- Specify a custom timeout for new connections to this public URI.

If this is not possible using the Graph API, what could our customer's developers use instead of the Graph API to guarantee more secure data transfers? The increased security is a hard requirement for this customer due to the more sensitive nature of the data stored in these files.

Also, we wonder if Microsoft Flow is using also the Graph API in the background for accessing OneDrive? Otherwise, this could be an alternative.

Comment: Please look into this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and see if this can fit in your scenario.

Comment: I think let me answer this. You need to look at the permission resource, which uses facets to provide information about the kind of permission represented by the resource. Permissions with a link facet represent sharing links created on the item. Sharing links contain a unique token that provides access to the item for anyone with the link. Also permissions with an invitation facet represent permissions added by inviting specific users or groups to have access to the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. We will look into this new information.

Comment: Cool. Let us know how it goes

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: I don't know actually. I asked this for a customer. If I know more I will let you know here.